# Jekyll problems with publishing on GitPages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have just created my first jekyll page, trying to use github.io

What am I doing wrong, as the page seems to serve correctly on my local machine yet it does not on the GitPages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `github.io` URL, the exact URL of your GitHub page depends on the name of your repository.

This is explained here in the GitHub Page documentation:
[**User, Organization, and Project Pages**](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)

- If you want your website URL to be https://cstml.github.io/ *(called ["user page"](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages) in the docs)*, the repository **must** be named `username.github.io`, i.e. in your case:
  https://github.com/cstml/cstml.github.io
- If you want your website URL to be https://cstml.github.io/some-sub-dir *(called ["project page"](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages) in the docs)*, the repository must be named `some-sub-dir`, i.e. in your case:
  https://github.com/cstml/some-sub-dir

Answer (score 0):

In my search for trying to solve it I have changed the name of the repository to my cstml.github.io GitHub-pages and that seems to have fixed it. Don't really understand why that is at the moment but it seems to be working.